# ¿Como añadir item de un listview a otro listview?

Tags: android, android-studio, lista, listview, android-listview

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de APPS y estoy diseñando una para crear sesiones de entrenamiento en la cual cada ejercicio se divide por grupo muscular y esos ejercicios los he puesto en un listview, hasta ahí todo esta bien [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GelUH.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, lo que quiero es poder pasar una copia de uno de los item por ejemplo "CICLISMO" de la lista de "CARDIO" a otra lista que esta en otra activity y la verdad no encuentro solución a ese requerimiento, quiero que me den un proyecto de ejemplo para analizarlo o me ayudaran con una respuesta de como hacer esto, apreciaría mucho una ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu `ListView` no se limita a texto, tendrás que usar tu propio `ArrayAdapter`, en este caso usaremos una clase propia como tipo de ArrayAdapter.

```
public class MiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MiItem> {

    private List<MiItem> items;

    public MiAdapter(Context context, List<MiItem> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.layout_de_mi_item, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MiItem item = items.get(position);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout_layout_de_mi_item, null);
        TextView miTexto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mi_texto);
        ImageView miImagen = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mi_imagen);
        miTexto.setText(item.getTexto());
        miImage.setImageResource(item.getImagen());
        return view;
    }

}
```

Ahora crearemos nuestra clase llamado `MiItem` donde estará la información de nuestros items.

```
public class MiItem {

    private String texto;
    private int imagen;

    public MiItem(String texto, int imagen) {
        this.texto = texto;
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public int getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

}
```

El contenedor de los items estarán en una array:

```
List<MiItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(new MiItem("Uno", R.drawable.one));
items.add(new MiItem("Dos", R.drawable.two));
MiAdapter adapter = new MiAdapter(this, items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**AHORA PARA COPIAR ITEMS:**

```
//Supongamos que items2 ya tiene items

//Vamos a añadir el nuevo item en el primer puesto (index 0), copiando el primer item de la lista original
items2.add(0, items.get(0));
//Si quieres añadir al último, quita el "0, "
MiAdapter adapter = new MiAdapter(this, items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Gracias, trabajare así como me indicaste y te diré como me resulto todo.